# When I use this code in ASP.NET MVC, it inserts 2 rows into the database.. 1 is empty and the other is with data i input

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, insert

```
com.CommandText = "insert into Merit (p_id, p_type_id, Prog_id, T_id, q_id, status_id) values((select p_id from personal_info where cnic='" + In.CNIC+"'), (select p_type_id from Prog_type where p_type_name='"+In.Program_Type+"'), (select Prog_id from Programme where prog_name='"+In.Program+ "'), (select T_id from Timing where Timing='" +In.Timing+ "'), (select q_id from Quota where q_name='" +In.Quota+ "'), 1)";
com.Connection = con;
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should ***NEVER EVER*** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)